# How to connect to shh without username and password for reverse tunneling

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, tunnel

Is it possible to connect to a ssh server (to create a tunnel) just with just:

`ssh -R sPort:localhost:cPort myDomain.com`

instead of:

`ssh -R sPort:localhost:cPort user@myDomain.com` (which also requires to login with a password)?

edit: applied suggested edits on the question.

Answer (score 0):

By default, ssh uses the current user's username when you don't supply one in the command. If the username you want to log in as in `myDomain.com` is not the same as that of your current local user, you can add a host-specific setting in your ssh config (located at `~/.ssh/config`):

```
Host myDomain.com
    User yourUserName
```

To log in without a password, you will need to copy your public key to the remote host so that it's recognized as an authorized key. Your public key is most likely going to be at `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` if you didn't change the defaults while generating the key pair. To copy the public key to the server, run the following command in your local machine:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/mykey yourUserName@myDomain.com
```

You should now be able to create a tunnel with just `ssh -R sPort:localhost:cPort myDomain.com` without having to enter the password.

Answer (score 0):

this is a really flawed question.

it's nothing to do with ubuntu.. and really nothing to do with reverse tunnel either.

and this would apply to command line SSH (Any standard implementation)..

You set up passwordless SSH. Then you can connect such that it makes a reverse tunnel or makes a regular tunnel, or no tunnel.

And to set up passwordless SSH, you can look it up, you can see then there's ssh-copy-id which can be used, or the few commands that are the manual equivalent of that.

And then hey presto you can do ssh user@blah,   and for a reverse tunnel you already have the options there for it written into your command in your example.

You just wanted passwordless SSH. That's an easily googlable thing.

(You do still need to specify the user, unless the user on the remote system happens to be the same username as the username on the local system,.. so makes seuse to put user@.  The other thing is it's possible to make a local ssh confugration file that puts the username in and then you can skip the username option).